# is mappedBy in hibernate defined as per schema definition or is it defined logically?

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, hibernate-mapping

I have the following situation:

One Destination can have Many Aliases

**Logically**: I would like Destination to be the owner of this relationship, since if there was no destination, alias would not hold any meaning.

However, the database schema is like this:

[image: Destination-Alias relationship]

DestinationAlias has idDestination as the Foreign Key and thus the @JoinColumn in hibernate annotation would be on DestinationAlias:

Destination:

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade={CascadeType.ALL}, mappedBy = "mainCity")
    public Set<DestinationAlias> getAliases() {
        return aliases;
    }
```

DestinationAlias:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name="IDDESTINATION", nullable=false)
    public Destination getMainCity() {
        return mainCity;
    }
```

From this definition, DestinationAlias is the owner of this relationship since the `mappedBy` is an attribute on Destination class.

Does hibernate require me to follow the `database schema` and mark entity as the owner of the relationship or can it be done based on `Logical` reasons ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ownership affects how hibernate would model the underlying database tables. If you omit the mappedBy attribute, hibernate would generate a join-table (like for an M-M relationship) between Destination and DestinationAlias, instead of a simple join column. Other than that, I'm curious as to what your actual issue is here. Is this purely cosmetic, or are there functional issues in play for you here?

EDIT: as this seems to be a purely cosmetic issue, my advice is to just accept the Hibernate semantic. While I agree that it might appear counter-intuitive that Hibernate would call DestinationAlias the "owner", that is just the nomenclature Hibernate decided on. It's not unique either and it comes from the notion that the "owner" is where the join-column resides.

Don't waste time trying to force hibernate to conform to your definitions when you don't have to.

Comment: My current issue is, DestinationAlias is the owner of this relationship and semantically, I'd like Destination to be the owner. The code works fine otherwise.